# OpenMediaVault on raspberry pi 4: Error making Scheduled Jobs

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi, openmediavault

I'm trying to launch the command:

```
source /srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-e7874961-1866-43e8-9cdb-503276f500b6/Scripts/Scheduled\ Jobs/telegrambot.sh
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
Errore #0:
OMV\ExecException: Failed to execute command 'export PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin; export LANG=C.UTF-8; export SHELL=/bin/sh; sudo --shell --non-interactive --user='root' -- /var/lib/openmediavault/cron.d/userdefined-6805cace-24e4-4582-9961-3347e2c3ed1b 2>&1' with exit code '127': /var/lib/openmediavault/cron.d/userdefined-6805cace-24e4-4582-9961-3347e2c3ed1b: 4: /var/lib/openmediavault/cron.d/userdefined-6805cace-24e4-4582-9961-3347e2c3ed1b:
source: not found
 in /usr/share/openmediavault/engined/rpc/cron.inc:185
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/php/openmediavault/rpc/serviceabstract.inc(588): Engined\Rpc\Cron->Engined\Rpc\{closure}('/tmp/bgstatus70...', '/tmp/bgoutputfp...')
#1 /usr/share/openmediavault/engined/rpc/cron.inc(189): OMV\Rpc\ServiceAbstract->execBgProc(Object(Closure))
#2 [internal function]: Engined\Rpc\Cron->execute(Array, Array)
#3 /usr/share/php/openmediavault/rpc/serviceabstract.inc(123): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 /usr/share/php/openmediavault/rpc/rpc.inc(86): OMV\Rpc\ServiceAbstract->callMethod('execute', Array, Array)
#5 /usr/sbin/omv-engined(537): OMV\Rpc\Rpc::call('Cron', 'execute', Array, Array, 1)
#6 {main}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar error, and what solved the issue for me was to remove the cron time indication in the command of the openmediavault scheduled job form.

For example:

- instead of `*/5 * * * * ~/duckdns/duck.sh >/dev/null 2>&1`
- add `~/duckdns/duck.sh >/dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: Thank you, I'll try!